# SDL Hello World program does not output message

Tags: c++, dll, sdl

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
17:23:46 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SDL2_program_59 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-ID:\\SDL2_inc_lib\\SDL2-2.0.8\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\SDL2" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\SDL2_program_59.o" "..\\src\\SDL2_program_59.cpp" 
g++ "-LD:\\SDL2_inc_lib\\SDL2-2.0.8\\i686-w64-mingw32\\lib" -o SDL2_program_59.exe "src\\SDL2_program_59.o" -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 
D:\SDL2_inc_lib\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function `main_utf8':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.8-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.8-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
```

I fixed  the SDL_main  error by adding argument to main() function such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** args) {
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile and run the program without problem. But I cannot see the "hello world" message in the screen.  If I comment out the SDL.h include line, I do see the message.  What is the problem ?

Comment: Run your program as a command in a terminal window. Details are operating system specific. Consider also compiling with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then running your executable in a debugger (like [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)...)

Comment: If I comment out the  SDL.h line. I do see the "hello world" message.

Comment: IIRC the `SDL2Main` "library" contains a `main` function, you should not have it yourself. Instead your code should have the `SDL_main` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's actually just a preprocessor definition: `#define main SDLmain` or something like that, so you actually still need a main function, but it does give weird errors

Answer (score 0):

Windows have big distinction between 'console' and 'GUI' applications. Recent SDL2 can handle both, but ultimately it is the linker that decides which application type you have. With gcc/mingw, it is controlled by `-mconsole` and `-mwindows` switches. E.g. with your source code in question:

```
> g++ test.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mconsole
> a.exe
hello world
> g++ test.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows
> a.exe
>
```

The output is still there, but `stdout` is no longer connected to console for GUI application so you don't see it in console, but you'll have it in debugger or if you'll redirect `stdout` to other place, e.g.:

```
> a.exe | more
hello world
```

It is also possible to handle console output on application side by redirecting `stdin`/`stdout` to `CONIN$` and `CONOUT$`, but that way I suppose you'll lose redirection ability on calling side.

Comment: "-mconsole"  does not work for me.    However if I put    #undef  main   before main() function ,  I can see hello world in console.  But  putting #undef main     seems not make sense.

Comment: Hi keltar,  I got another problem which is  I cannot make the SDL window to show up. Please refer to the answer above for the details.

Comment: @user2818066 do you set said flag for both compilation and linking steps? As for window creation, it is unrelated, as you can still create window from console application, so more info on your problem is required (probably in separate question).